# Get rid of extraneous merge commits on topic/feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge

Say we create a topic/feature branch and we are working on it for a week. To keep up to date with the integration branch we could use `git rebase`, but for the sake of the question let's use `git merge`. So we create merge commits in our feature branch - merging the integration branch into the feature branch, as we go.

I believe these merge commits are basically useless noise at the end of the day. Is there a good way to get rid of these merge commits when merging the feature branch into the integration branch when you are done with the feature? I assume squashing the branch into one commit is one way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you merged and not rebased then squashing is the way to 'remove' merge commit.

I don't do it always though, especially when the feature is large and the merges needed conflict resolution.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe these merge commits are basically useless noise at the end of the day. Is there a good way to get rid of these merge commits

Tell git what branch you're tracking and your command is a plain `git rebase`.

Make `wizzo` track dev with e.g. `git branch -t wizzo dev`, work some on dev, work some on wizzo, merge, work more on both, you get something like this:

> ```
> * f7b551f (dev) 4dev
> | * 982b0c7 (HEAD -> wizzo) 3wiz
> | *   5de6750 Merge branch 'dev' into wizzo
> | |\  
> | |/  
> |/|   
> * | 2e8c7ec 1dev
> | * a320e00 2wiz
> |/  
> * c823194 Init
> ```

After a plain `git rebase`:

> ```
> * 096cbfc (HEAD -> wizzo) 3wiz
> * 8e5d6c5 2wiz
> * f7b551f (dev) 4dev
> * 2e8c7ec 1dev
> * c823194 Init
> ```

`git rerere` is built to make this workflow as painless as possible, it remembers how you resolved merge conflicts so when you eventually rebase back like this a month from now, even if you don't remember what you did, Git does.

Answer (score 0):

Tymtam is right, but if you want to do it by hand you can do:

```
git checkout a

git merge b

git reset --soft origin/a

git add -A

git commit -m "Single commit all changes"
```